# In Tailwind CSS, installing the PostCSS plugin, when I run "npm run build" it shows me the below error. I tried a lot of time. What should I do?

Tags: css, tailwind-css, postcss

In Windows, under [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell):

```
cd D:\TailwindCSS
cd gs3
npm run build
```

#### Output

> gs3@1.0.0 build D:\TailwindCSS\gs3 
> postcss ./src/tailwind.css -o ./public/tailwind.css
>
> internal/modules/run_main.js:54 
> internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
> ^

> Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME]: Only file and data URLs 
> are supported by the default ESM loader 
> ←[90m    at Loader.defaultResolve [as _resolve] 
> (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:669:11)←[39m 
> ←[90m    at Loader.resolve 
> (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:97:40)←[39m 
> ←[90m    at Loader.getModuleJob 
> (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:243:28)←[39m 
> ←[90m    at ModuleWrap. 
> (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:42:40)←[39m 
> ←[90m    at link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:41:36)←[39m { 
> code: ←[32m'ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME'←[39m 
> } 
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE 
> npm ERR! errno 1 
> npm ERR! gs3@1.0.0 build: `postcss ./src/tailwind.css -o \ ./public/tailwind.css` 
> npm ERR! Exit status 1 
> npm ERR! 
> npm ERR! Failed at the gs3@1.0.0 build script. 
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely 
> additional logging output above. \
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: 
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm- 
> cache_logs\2021-12-01T04_42_15_907Z-debug.log

Comment: I am using Windows7-x86.

Comment: You need to ask a question in your post and format your code.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Node.js v12.18; technically, [EMS](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2018/03/es-modules-a-cartoon-deep-dive/) is only supported in Node.js v12.20+

Update your Node.js to the latest version.